# Learning JavaScript, copied code word for word from a book and code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

My sister's boyfriend gave me his old books so I could try and learn web development.  I am completely new to JavaScript and am trying to copy every example from the book I am reading so I have references and get experience.  This is the third example in the entire book and I cannot get it to run right, despite copying the example word for word.

After I hit compute the bottom part of the website does not change, when it is supposed to display the numbers after the calculations...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Loan Calculator</title>
<style>
    /* This is a CSS style sheet:  it adds style to the program output */
    .result {font-weight: bold; } /* For elements with class="result" */
    #payment { text-decoration: underline; } /* For elemnt with id="payment" */
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- This is an HTML form that allows the user to enter data and allows
JavaScript to display the results it computes back to the user. The
form elemnets are embedded in a table to improve their appearnce.
The form itself is given the name "laondata", and the fields within
the form are given names such as "interst" and "years". These
field names are used in the JavaScript code that follows the form.
Note that some of the form elements define "onchange" or "onclick"
event handlers. These specify strings of JavaScript code to be
executed when the user enters data or clicks on a button.-->

<form name="loandata">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1) Amount of the loan (any currency):</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="principal" onchange="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2) Annual percentage rate of intrest:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="interest" onchange="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>3) Repayment period in years:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="years" onchange="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><b>Payment Information:</b></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4) Your monthly payment:</td>
            <td>$<span class="result" id="payment"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5) Your total payment:</td>
            <td>$<span class="result" id="total"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6) Your total intrest payments:</td>
            <td>$<span class="result" id="totalinterest"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
/* This is the JavaScript function that makes the example work.  Note that
this script defines the calculate() function called bt the event handlers
in the form. The function reads cvalues from the form <input> fields using
the names defined in the previous HTML code. It outputs its results into
the named <span> elements. */
function calculate(){
    //Get the user's input from teh form.  Asume it is all valid.
    //Convert interest from a percentage to a decimal, and convert
    //from an annual rate to a monthly rate. Convert payment period in years
    //to the number of monthly payments
    var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
    var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
    var payments = document.loandata.payments.value * 12;

    //Now compute the monthly payment figure, using esoteric math.
    var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
    var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

    //Get named <span> elements from the form.
    var payment = document.getElementByID("payment");
    var total = document.getElementByID("total");
    var totalinterest = document.getElementByID("totalinterest");

    //check that the result is a finite number.  If so, display the
    //results by setting the HTML content of each <span> element.
    if (isFinite(monthly)) {
        payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
        total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
        totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);
    }

    //Otherwise the user's input was probably invaild, so display nothing
    else{
        payment.innerHTML = "";
        total.innerHTML = "";
        totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Very first place to start debugging is to learn to use browser developer tools. Hit F12 and look for errors thrown in console

Comment: There are several errors that crop up as you fix prior ones. One is about `getElementByID()` which you can then search in google which would lead you to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById Then double check method spelling

Comment: First error I see is `document.loandata.payments is undefined` ...means it doesn't exist so you can't get the `value` of an input that doesn't exist.  `document.loandata` is the form.... then payments would be an input in the form.

Comment: Try changing that to a hard code number for now (or modify form so it does exist)...then go to next error

Comment: These error codes are just confusing me.  It says my document.getElementById is not a function...

Comment: Nevermind.  the D was capitalized... I did not see that,  Ha.  It works now.  the .payments was supposed to be .years instead, too.  Thank you.

Comment: OK...so now you know why it was "not a function" and have a better feel for what that error message means. Learning about debugging is just as important as learning to write the code

Comment: Note that many common error messages pasted into google will turn up numerous results. You may not find immediate solution but many times will get a better idea of what problem is. Researching bugs/errors is also a significant part of coding